# Infinite scrolling react.js

Tags: reactjs

{this.state.articles.map((element) => {
return 
<NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title : ""} description={element.description ?                  element.description : ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} />

`Error occurs : react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key`

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you're trying to create a list of elements in React, but not using key property properly. When you create a list of elements, each element should have a unique key property. So that React can identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed, and it's essential for the efficient update and re-render of the component. If there's no unique id in your element, you can use the index of the map function, or uuid package like so:

```
    {this.state.articles.map((element, index) => { 
    return (
        <NewsItem 
            key={index}  // this is our unique key
            title={element.title ? element.title : ""}
            description={element.description ? element.description : ""}
            imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
            newsUrl={element.url}
            author={element.author}
            date={element.publishedAt}
            source={element.source.name}
        />
    )
})}
```

Here is the solution with uuidv4

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

{this.state.articles.map((element) => { 
    return (
        <NewsItem 
            key={uuidv4()}  // unique key generated by uuid
            title={element.title ? element.title : ""}
            description={element.description ? element.description : ""}
            imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
            newsUrl={element.url}
            author={element.author}
            date={element.publishedAt}
            source={element.source.name}
        />
    )
})}
```